# bs4 getting a tag's value

Tags: beautifulsoup, tags

Here's html code I'm working on.

```
<div class="input-group m-b">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
   $
   </span>
   <input class="form-text form-control input-lg-3" disabled="disabled" 
   groupfields="$" id="edit-transfer--3" maxlength="128" 
   name="transfer_d" size="60" type="text" value="71"/>
</div>
```

What I want is to get "71" which is the value of a "value" tag

I've tried

```
elem = soup.find('input', attrs={'id':'edit-transfer--3'})
print(elem)
```

and gives

```
<input class="form-text form-control input-lg-3" disabled="disabled" groupfields="$" id="edit-transfer--3" maxlength="128" name="transfer_d" size="60" type="text" value="71"/>
```

and I'm stuck
`print(elem.find('value')` gives me None
and

```
print(elemd.find('value').get_text())
```

gives me an error

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

How can I extract the value from the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div class="input-group m-b">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
   $
   </span>
   <input class="form-text form-control input-lg-3" disabled="disabled" 
   groupfields="$" id="edit-transfer--3" maxlength="128" 
   name="transfer_d" size="60" type="text" value="71"/>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
elem = soup.find('input', attrs={'id':'edit-transfer--3'})

print(elem['value'])
```

returns

```
71
```

- The `find` method is used to find child elements from the parent. Since value is an attribute and there's no element tag called value, None is returned.
- The `get_text` method will only extract the `innerText` of the element. Since the previous `find` returned None, it throws the error.

To get a specific attribute you need to use square brackets.

Comment: Great!! So simple and It works!! I think I'm lack of some fundamental stuff. You filled me up.